# Run an Ajax script without click event

Tags: woocommerce

In "woocommerce product finder" plugin, the first query field row display by default and if the user want to add another filed row based on product attributes, have to click on + button below the default row. How can I load all rows on page load without click event?

the php code:

```
    public static function search_form( $atts = array(), $show_cat = false ) {
    $action = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );

    $att_string = implode( $atts , ',' );

    $html = '<form name="wc_product_finder" id="wc_product_finder" class="woocommerce" action="' . esc_url( $action ) . '" method="get">
                <fieldset>
                <legend>' . __( 'Product Finder','woocommerce-product-finder' ) . '</legend>
                <input type="hidden" id="search_attributes" value="' . $att_string . '" />
                <input type="hidden" id="show_cat" value="' . json_encode( $show_cat ) . '" />
                <input type="hidden" name="adv_search" value="wc" />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />';

    $html .= self::relation_dropdown();

    if ( ( isset( $_GET['adv_search'] ) && 'wc' === $_GET['adv_search'] ) && isset( $_GET['tax'][0] ) ) {
        foreach ( $_GET['tax'] as $row => $tax ) {
            $html .= self::search_row( $row , $atts , $show_cat , true );
        }
    } else {
        $html .= self::search_row( 0 , $atts , $show_cat );
    }

    $html .= '<div id="last_row" style="display:none;">0</div>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="add_row" class="add_row" title="افزودن سطر جدید"><span class="loader">&nbsp;</span><span class="plus">+</span> <span class="text">' . __( 'Add row', 'woocommerce-product-finder' ) . '</span></a>';

    $string = '';
    if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        $string = $_GET['s'];
    }
    $html .= '<div class="form-row form-row-first keywords"><label for="s">' . __( 'Keywords', 'woocommerce-product-finder' ) . '</label><input type="text" name="s" placeholder="' . __( 'Keywords', 'woocommerce-product-finder' ) . '" value="' . $string . '"/></div>';

    if ( apply_filters( 'product_finder_show_price_slider', true ) ) {
        $html .= self::price_slider();
    }

    $html .= '<div class="form-row form-row-wide form-row-submit"><input type="submit" class="button" value="' . __( 'Search' , 'woocommerce-product-finder' ) . '" /></div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>';

    return $html;
}
```

and here is the jquery script:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

jQuery( '#wc_product_finder #add_row' ).css('display', 'block').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery( '#add_row .loader' ).show();
    jQuery( '#add_row .plus' ).hide();
    var last_row = parseInt( jQuery( '#last_row' ).text() );
    var next_row = last_row + 1;
    var show_cat = jQuery( '#show_cat' ).val();
    var search_attributes = jQuery( '#search_attributes' ).val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: wc_product_finder_data.ajax_url,
        data: 'action=wc_product_finder_add_row&row=' + next_row + '&show_cat=' + show_cat + '&search_attributes=' + search_attributes,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( response ) {
            if( response ) {
                jQuery( '#last_row' ).before( response );
                jQuery( '#last_row' ).text( next_row );
                jQuery( '#search_row_' + next_row ).slideDown( 'fast' , function() {
                    jQuery( '#add_row .plus' ).show();
                    jQuery( '#add_row .loader' ).hide();
                });

            } else {

            }
        }
    });

});
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry for question title mistake. That was jQuery not Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Either invoke the click yourself or assign the function a name and invoke the function.

Either

```js
jQuery( '#wc_product_finder #add_row' ).css('display', 'block').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery( '#add_row .loader' ).show();
    jQuery( '#add_row .plus' ).hide();
    var last_row = parseInt( jQuery( '#last_row' ).text() );
    var next_row = last_row + 1;
    var show_cat = jQuery( '#show_cat' ).val();
    var search_attributes = jQuery( '#search_attributes' ).val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: wc_product_finder_data.ajax_url,
        data: 'action=wc_product_finder_add_row&row=' + next_row + '&show_cat=' + show_cat + '&search_attributes=' + search_attributes,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( response ) {
            if( response ) {
                jQuery( '#last_row' ).before( response );
                jQuery( '#last_row' ).text( next_row );
                jQuery( '#search_row_' + next_row ).slideDown( 'fast' , function() {
                    jQuery( '#add_row .plus' ).show();
                    jQuery( '#add_row .loader' ).hide();
                });

            } else {

            }
        }
    });

});

// dispatch click yourself
jQuery( '#wc_product_finder #add_row' ).click()
```

or

```js
// declare click handler
function handleClick(e) {
    e && e.preventDefault();
    jQuery( '#add_row .loader' ).show();
    jQuery( '#add_row .plus' ).hide();
    var last_row = parseInt( jQuery( '#last_row' ).text() );
    var next_row = last_row + 1;
    var show_cat = jQuery( '#show_cat' ).val();
    var search_attributes = jQuery( '#search_attributes' ).val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: wc_product_finder_data.ajax_url,
        data: 'action=wc_product_finder_add_row&row=' + next_row + '&show_cat=' + show_cat + '&search_attributes=' + search_attributes,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( response ) {
            if( response ) {
                jQuery( '#last_row' ).before( response );
                jQuery( '#last_row' ).text( next_row );
                jQuery( '#search_row_' + next_row ).slideDown( 'fast' , function() {
                    jQuery( '#add_row .plus' ).show();
                    jQuery( '#add_row .loader' ).hide();
                });

            } else {

            }
        }
    });

// bind handler to click event
jQuery( '#wc_product_finder #add_row' ).css('display', 'block').click(handleClick)

// invoke function
handleClick()
```